# Even odd sort, keep odds out first in order of appearance recursion Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, recursion

How would I sort the array to be between even and odds with the order of appearance of the number in the same order such as [2 1 4 6 3 9 8] using recursion to provide this [1 3 9 2 4 6 8]? Some help or examples using Java would be greatly appreciated.

This code does similar work, just having a hard time with the problem at hand.

[Sorting an array recursively in Java with even numbers appearing in front of array.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540971/sorting-an-array-recursively-in-java-with-even-numbers-appearing-in-front-of-arr)

This is the portion giving issues with how to handle even numbers that are side by side. No loops are to be used.

```
public static int[] SplitOdds(int input[], int left, int next){     
    int[] temp = new int[1];
    int[] temp2 = new int[1];
    if (input.length == 1)
        {return input;}
    if (input.length ==2){
        temp[0] = input[left];
        input[left] = input[next];
        input[next] = temp[0];
        return input;}
    if (input[left]%2!=0 && input[next]%2==0)
        {return SplitOdds(input, left+1, next+1);}
    if(input[left]%2==0 && input[next]%2!=0){
        temp[0] = input[left];
        input[left] = input[next];
        input[next] = temp[0];
        return  SplitOdds(input, left+1, next+1);}
    if(input[left]%2!=0&&input[next]%2!=0)
        return SplitOdds(input, left+1, next+1);
    if(input[left]%2==0&&input[next]%2==0){
        int j = next;
        temp[0]=input[left];
        return SplitOdds(input, left, next+1);}
        else if(input[next]%2!=0){
            //temp2[0]=input[j];
            //input[left]=input[next];
            input[left+1] = temp2[0];       
        return SplitOdds(input, left, next+1);}
    else if(next == input.length)
    {left = 1; 
    next = 2;}
    return input;
    }
```

Comment: Show us your efforts.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[]{2, 1, 4, 6, 3, 9, 8}; // what to sort?

// The sorting logic is the same for anything that is Comparable. Only the criteria (ie. what makes a value bigger than another?) changes
Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
        if(i1%2 != i2%2) { // comparing an odd number with an even?
            return i1%2==0? 1:-1; // then odd comes before even
        }

        return i1 - i2; // else biggest number comes after smaller ones
    }
});

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // basic display
```

Comment: I will give that a try. I may have gone way to complex with mine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the possible approaches :

```
  @Test
  public void test() {
    List<Integer> testSource = Arrays.asList(1, 8, 2, 4, 6, 9, 5, 3);

    Collections.sort(testSource, new Comparator<Integer>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        if (o1 % 2 == o2 % 2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        } else {
          return o1 % 2 == 1 ? -1 : 1;
        }
      }
    });
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8), testSource);
  }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this  looks to be using linked lists. I haven't got to the point of using those, but the recursive call should be a huge help!  Thank you!

Comment: Correction on that, it looks like you're using an enhanced for loop.

Comment: This example works using ArrayList implementation, not LinkedList. In `Java 8` this approach will use default implementation of `List.sort(Comparator<? super E> c)` interface method. The complexity : `lg(n)` and the algorithm called `Merge Sort`